# install software using pydroid 3 terminal

Tags: python, android, git, terminal, pydroid

I was working on django project on PC but i want to use my phone to continue progress on any time and any place so i have pydroid 3 ide and build in terminal, when i use apt in terminal to download git and clone repo this massage show up:
`

/storage/emulated/0 $ apt

sh: apt: not found

`

I tried help command and this list of command show up, which one for installing software?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tVzV.png)

Comment: There exists a similar question [Install Git in Pydroid 3 terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58672168/295004) but I don't believe PyDroid3 has curl or make so the existing answer seems incomplete. You may want to look at [Termux](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.termux/) which does has [some development support](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Development_Environments)